# weightage attributes

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn

If I have a dataset with binary classification and has many attributes with value of  (0 or 1) means the occurrence of attribute is represented by 1 and absence is represented by 0, can I add weight of that attributes as separate column in dataset before applying classifier model?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You don't really need a new column, you could just convert your existing columns to their representative weights.

I would suggest for you to:

1. Convert your `[0,1]` to `[-1,1]`;
2. Multiply by a float weight in the range `[0.0, 1.0]`.

I suggest you change the range from `[0, 1]` to `[-1,1]` because of the following example where it is not possible to differentiate the two:

```
attribute_value = 0
weight = 1.0
final_value = attribute_value × weight = 0.0

attribute_value = 1
weight = 0.0
final_value = attribute_value × weight = 0.0
```

However, if you change the range, you get:

```
attribute_value = 0
attribute_value_new = -1
weight = 1.0
final_value = attribute_value_new × weight = -1.0

attribute_value = 1
attribute_value_new = 1
weight = 0.0
final_value = attribute_value_new × weight = 0.0
```

A full example would be:

```
X = [
    [0, 1, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 1]
]

X_transformed = [
    [-1,  1, -1, 1],
    [-1, -1,  1, 1]
]

column_weights = [1, 0, 0.5, 0.25]

weighted_X = [
    [-1, 0, -0.5, 0.25],
    [-1, 0,  0.5, 0.25]
]
```

Comment: Thanks BrunoGl.

Comment: @Iona glad I could help. If you feel like you answer has been answer, please feel free to mark this as the accepted answer.